# Use Combo boxs as label of the every columns(TableView)

Tags: c++, tableview, qt-creator

How can I use a combo box as the header of columns?

I think know I need to use `setHorizontalHeader(QHeaderView)` but How can I use `QAbstractItemModel` to make a comboBox model for `QHeaderView.setModel(QAbstractItemModel)` ,so I can use it for `setHorizontalHeader(QHeaderView)` ?

or Do I need to use `QItemDelegate`?